# Finding velocity of air using Hare apparatus (Bernoulli`s principle )

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

> A horizontal stream of air is blown just above the open end of the hares apparatus with an initial speed "V". The density of air is 1.2 kgm<sup>-3</sup>.Then the water column rises to 6 cm in the respective limb.Density of water is 10<sup>3</sup> kgm<sup>-3</sup>
>
> **Question**:  Find "V" using Bernoulli`s principle

[image]

Here`s how I attempted the question,

$$
\frac{1}{2}\rho_{air} V^2\:+\rho_{air} gh\:=h\rho_{water} g \\
\frac{1}{2}\rho _{air}\:V^2\:=h\rho _{water}\:g\:-\:\rho \:_{air}\:gh
$$
$$ \frac{1}{2}\:\cdot 1.2\cdot \:V^2\:=\frac{6}{100}\cdot 1000\:\cdot 10\:-\:1.2\cdot \:10\cdot \frac{6}{100} \\V\:=\sqrt{10^3-1.2} $$

`FYI This is not a Homework question ,this question is from my last term test . I got it wrong . Im trying to redo this question and Im stuck . I keep getting the same answer`
How to solve this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p_{top}$ is the low pressure occurring at the top, then the entire fluid column is held by a pressure difference equal to $p_{ambient}-p_{top}=p_{ambient}-(p_{ambient}-\frac{1}{2}\rho_{air}V^2)=\frac{1}{2}\rho_{air}V^2$. Total pressure due to fluid column is $\rho_{water}gh_{water}+\rho_{air}gh_{air}\approx \rho_{water}gh_{water}$. Equate the two to get your answer.

Comment: when I attempted the question , i also considered the potential energy at the top point. Is that incorrect ?

Comment: @ShanilkaHaturusinghe Well if the streamline is horizontal then there is no change in potential energy. Since the problem doesn't mention anything, just assume the simplest case.